# How to look up "all things astrophysical" about A=9 (or other light isobars)?

Tags: astrophysics, stellar-astrophysics, nucleosynthesis

All the light [isobars](https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-isotopes-and-vs-isobars-and-vs-isotones) (group with same atomic <s>number</s> mass) are interesting and quirky, but let's use A=9 as an example. <sup>9</sup>C and <sup>9</sup>Li beta decay to particle unbound states in <sup>9</sup>B and <sup>9</sup>Be (except to <sup>9</sup>Be's ground state), and those unbound states decay through both p/n + <sup>8</sup>Be (which decays to 2<sup>4</sup>He) + <sup>4</sup>He) and <sup>4</sup>He + <sup>5</sup>Li/<sup>5</sup>He (which then decay to p/n + <sup>4</sup>He).

Of course the A=4,5 and 8 isobars are famous for their roles in nucleosynthesis, the short lived 16.6 MeV state in <sup>8</sup>Be participating in the [triple alpha process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple-alpha_process)) being one example, but I'm curious to what extent <sup>9</sup>C, <sup>9</sup>B, <sup>9</sup>Be and <sup>9</sup>Li have astrophysical implications.

**Question:** How to look up "all things astrophysical" about A=9 or other light isobars? Is there some kind of central clearing house for such information that can be queried by atomic <s>number</s> mass?

Here "all things astrophysical" means all of the known, studied or proposed ways that a given nucleus participates in or has some specific implication in some astrophysical process.

Comment: Same atomic number?  Mass number, maybe?

Comment: @DJohnM yes indeed, thank you for catching that! I've added a correction.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [reaclib library](https://reaclib.jinaweb.org/search.php) and search "mass A" with `start` and `end` values = 9. That will give you a list of known reactions with atomic mass 9 atoms as well as their reaction rates and other useful information.

There's no central place, I know of, that lists where each reaction is important. To find if/where a reaction is important you need to either:

- Search the literature for each rate. Usually the papers that discuss new measurements of a particular rate will discuss its impact on astrophysical processes.
- Or you'll need to run models with/without the reactions of interest and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

My go-to places for nuclear reactions include:

The [Evaluated Nuclear Data File](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/endf/) database (I've linked to Brookhaven, there are a variety of other mirrors including the IAEA). This covers neutron and gamma reaction cross sections, both global and for specific reactions such as (n,2n) or (n,a).

Similarly, the sister [Evaluated Nuclear Structure Data File](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/) gets info on reactions that lead to a given nuclei. You might also want to investigate the other databases linked at the National Nuclear Data Center at BNL, including the [Experimental Nuclear Reaction Data](https://www-nds.iaea.org/exfor/).

For light nuclei, the [Nuclear Data Evaluation Project](https://nucldata.tunl.duke.edu/) at the Triangle Universities Nuclear Laboratory covers a range of data for A=3 to A=20. This is particularly nice for energy level diagrams comparing nuclei with the same A value.

Finally, should one have access, the journal [Nuclear Data Sheets](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/nuclear-data-sheets) has lots of info.